# Program that decodes a message in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

How can I take a text file that first lists a 2x2 matrix that was used to encrypt a message, followed by one integer per line (total 32 lines) that encode a message? Basically, I want to create a program that will:

1) Read and invert the 2x2 encryption matrix

2) Write a subroutine for determinant function to help invert matrix

3) Decrypt by reading in two integers at a time and inserting them into a character string (chracter*32 = full string)

And finally, print the hidden message.

I am pretty new to Fortran (and programming in general) but here is what I have so far and would appreciate any help.

```
program Program2

implicit none

INTEGER, DIMENSION(2,2) :: M, M2, M3
INTEGER :: B(32)
INTEGER :: row,col,max_rows,max_cols, Det, i, n, a
max_rows = 2
max_cols = 2

open(11, file = 'Data3.txt')

DO row = 1,max_rows
  READ(11,*) (M(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
END DO

!Finding the inverse of a 2x2 matrix and reassigning.
M2(1,1) = M(2,2)
M2(2,2) = M(1,1)
M2(1,2) = -M(1,2)
M2(2,1) = -M(2,1)

! Could not get determinant function to yield correct answer (calc by hand)
M3 = M2/-1
print*, M3
print*, Det

open(11, file = 'Data3.txt')
i = a

do i = 1, 16
    read(11,*) n
    print*, n
enddo

close(11)
end program Program2

! Determinant function for a 2x2 matrix
function Determinant(M2) result(Det)

   implicit none
   INTEGER, DIMENSION(2,2) :: M, M2, M3
   INTEGER :: B(32)
   INTEGER :: row,col,max_rows,max_cols, Det, i, n, a

   Det = M2(1,1)*M2(2,2) - M2(1,2)*M2(2,1)

end function Determinant
```

Here is the text file (or just a copy of what it looks like):

> ```
>     3          11
>        2           7
>     1488
>      955
>      703
>      458
>     1379
>      887
>     1465
>      943
>     1196
>      764
>     1392
>      895
>     1433
>      922
>     1403
>      902
>     1372
>      876
>     1467
>      943
>      697
>      454
>     1518
>      975
>     1596
>     1026
>     1392
>      895
>     1536
>      988
>      726
>      473
> ```

Comment: I can't see any question. This is a Qustion nad Answer site, do you have a question?

Comment: If there are any problems with your code, we need a thourough description of those problems. Error messages, wrong results... How wrong are they? How should the correct ones look?

Comment: you know you never use your function`determinant` .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to get your `Determinant` function working, it needs a type (see [Function has no implicit type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751863/function-has-no-implicit-type)):

```
INTEGER :: Determinant
```

**Edit:**
No need to be referenced as external, as pointed out in the comments. Thanks.

Then it can be used and it works well:

```
Det = Determinant(M2)
print*, Det
```

prints `-1`.

Second, could you please provide more explanation about what you want to do in step 3) so that we can help you out.

> 3) Decrypt by reading in two integers at a time and inserting them into a character string (chracter*32 = full string)

Comment: In step 3, essentially what I am trying to do is take two 2 integers and read them as if they were a 2x1 matrix. I want to first take M2 and divide by Det, get a new matrix (ie M3). Then take M3 (a 2x2) and multiply with two integers at a time (2x1) to get a matrix that holds the values for the ASCII characters. (ie 83 would be S). Is this clearer?