# Return type missmatch calling function

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran.f file and whant to compile it in Linux. I dont't know what I am doing wrong. I get the following error in my subroutine:

```
VHImpUmat.f:476:20:

  sv%Fm = get_Fm(T)                                                 !     $F_M(\Tb)$ limit stress obliquity (depends on $\theta$)
               1
Error: Return type mismatch of function ‘get_fm’ at (1) (UNKNOWN/REAL(8))
AVHImpUmat.f:476:14:

  sv%Fm = get_Fm(T)                                                 !      $F_M(\Tb)$ limit stress obliquity (depends on $\theta$)
          1
Error: Function ‘get_fm’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

My subroutine:

```
subroutine stiffness_and_derivatives(T,sv,mat,d,msg)
  use tools_lt
  use constitutive_names
  implicit none
  type (MATERIALCONSTANTS),intent(in) :: mat
  type (STATEVARIABLES),intent(inout) :: sv
  type (DERIVATIVES), intent(inout) :: d
  type (MESSAGE),intent(inout) :: msg
  character*40 :: whereIam
  real(8), intent(in) :: T(3,3)
  real(8), dimension(3,3,3,3,3,3) :: c,ctransp
  real(8) :: trT3,fac

  sv%Fm = get_Fm(T)                                                 !   $F_M(\Tb)$ limit stress obliquity (depends on $\theta$)
  sv%That = hated(T)                                                !    $\hat {\Tb} = \Tb / \tr \Tb$
  sv%LLhat= sv%Fm*sv%Fm*Idelta+mat%az2*(sv%That .out. sv%That)      !   linear hp stiffness $ \hat{\cE} = a^2 \left[ \left(\Frac{F_M}{a}\right)^2 \cI + \hTb \hTb \right] $
  sv%LL   = -( sv%trT/(3.0d0*mat%Cs) )* sv%LLhat                    !   $ \cE = \frac{-\tr\Tb}{3 \kappa} \hat{\cE}$
!----- dLLhatdT ----------
  trT3 = sv%trT**3                                                  !    $\tr^3 \Tb$
  fac =  mat%az2 / trT3
  c = (Idelta .out. T)                                              !   $c_{ijmnkl}= I_{ijmn}T_{kl}$
  ctransp = tpose35i46(c)                                           !   $c^T= c_{ijklmn}$
  d%dLLhatdT = fac * ( sv%trT*ctransp + sv%trT*(T .out. Idelta)
 &              - 2.0d0*( T .out. ( T .out. delta) ) )              !    $ \hat E_{ijklmn}'=a^2\left(\dfrac{ T_{rr} I_{ijmn}T_{kl} + T_{rr} T_{ij}I_{klmn}-2  T_{ij}T_{kl} \delta_{mn} }{ (T_{rr})^3}    +  2 \dfrac{F_M}{a} I_{ijkl}F'_{M\, mn}  \right)$
                                                                    !    $F'_M \approx 0$ is assumed
  d%dLLdT = -(1.0d0/(3.0d0*mat%Cs) )*((sv%LLhat .out. delta)        !   $\cE_{ }' = \frac{-1}{3 \kappa}  \hat\cE \oneb + \dfrac{-\tr \Tb}{3\kappa}\hat\cE'$
 &              + sv%trT*d%dLLhatdT )
end subroutine stiffness_and_derivatives
```

Comment: Where do you expect the function `get_Fm` to be defined?  Your compiler can't see it (which is what the second error means).

Comment: Related/possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751863/function-has-no-implicit-type  There are more hits when you search for the error message so more potential duplicates. Show us where the function is, it is in a different module or is it external?

Comment: side note: do not use `real(8)`. It is non-standard and not portable. Have a look at `real64` in `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module in Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

In your subroutine, you have the statement `implicit none`. This is very good and is considered good programming practice.

With this, you must specifically declare any user functions with their return type just like you declare your variables.

We really cannot see what kind of variable sv%Fm is since it is likely defined in one of those modules you use. For the sake of answering, lets say the Fm component of sv is a real(8) (hint in the error message): You would declare the function like this:

```
real(8) :: get_fm
```

You would do this at the top with the rest of the variable declarations.

The second error message `Error: Function ‘get_fm’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type` essentially tells you you did not declare the return type of your function when there is no implicit typing.

The first error message `Error: Return type mismatch of function ‘get_fm’ at (1) (UNKNOWN/REAL(8))` always lists 2 types. The first type is in the using program unit and the second type is the return value type in the function itself. Since you did not declare the function in your subroutine, it reports 'unknown' for that one. If, for example, you accidentally declared it as an integer function, it would have (integer/real(8)) there and that is a little more self-explanatory about the type mismatch.

So adding the 1 declaration makes both errors go away.

Comment: If the function is in another module, you should *not* declare the return type again in the calling subroutine. It won't fix anything.

Comment: Yes. But, since he is getting the error message, it is obviously not in the tools_lt nor the constitutive_names modules that he uses here. Somehow, he has to let subroutine stiffness_and_derivatives know the return type of this function.